# How to return type I explicitly passed as parameter?

Tags: java, generics, types, hamcrest

I want to store a type as parameter, but when I return it and check in within a JUnit test, I get something like

```
Expected: an instance of Java.lang.String
but: <class java.lang.String> is a java.lang.class
```

This is a minimalized example of the class...

```
public class ContextVariableResult<T> {
    private Class<T> type;

    public ContextVariableResult(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    //TODO doesn't work
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

I pass **String.class** as constructor parameter.

My test looks like this....

```
assertThat(result.getType(), instanceOf(String.class));
```

I thought that my hamcrest matcher is wrong, but I can't use **is(String.class)** or **isA(String.class)** due to compilation errors:

```
 The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#3-of ?>, 
     Matcher<String>)
```

I already tried to return the reflection object **Type**, I also tried to cast to **ParameterizedType**, but then I get ClassCastExceptions and so on.

I want the method result to be "String". What did I wrong? It would be much better if I don't need to pass the parameter **"String.class"**, but then I think I always get **type erasure** problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are checking that the return value is instance of string, e.g. `"hello"`. But your method return class `String`, i.e. `String.class`.

I guess that your method returns what you wanted. In this case you even do not have ot use `hamecrest` for your validation. The regular `JUnit`'s `Assert.assertEquals(String.class, result.getType())` will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

The class you've written is fine. Your test is incorrect, because a `Class<String>` is not an instance of `String`. Change the assertion:

```
assertThat(result.getType(), is(String.class));
// or
assertEquals(String.class, result.getType());
```

Comment: assertEquals works, but when I try to use the first one, Eclipse tells me `The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#4-of ?>, 
  Matcher<String>)`